# Passing Contact Form 7 Data to a Shortcode

Tags: php, forms, barcode

I am using Contact Form 7 to help me track products as they are received.

I would like to pass the data from a CF7 form field to a redirected page that has the 8080 Barcode shortcode on it, to help me make printable labels.

I cannot seem to figure out how to pass this data to the shortcode. I have also made a custom php file for the output page.

Some help would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anytime you have written code that is relevant to your question, it is a good idea to go ahead and post it -- that will help answerers know what approaches you have already tried. The more detail, the better!

Comment: How can you expect us to write out code... do expect us to know what you're working with exactly and that we can write magic code that just fits like a jigsaw at a guess? **add your relevant code** - without it, we can't do anything.